# Bash script doesn't set variable when run from script, but works fine from prompt

Tags: bash

Why does the following work from the prompt but fail when stuck inside a bash script?  The bash script produces one empty line leading me to believe the variable isn't being set:

```
echo "red sox" | read my_var
echo $my_var
```

UPDATE: Since I guess my example isn't working, what I'm really trying to do is take I/O and pipe it into a variable to so I can do things with it.  How do I do this?  I thought this should be taken care of by the `read` command, but maybe there's another way?

Comment: That doesn't work on my prompt.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Aye, doesn't work here either. If you already know the value "red sox" why not assign it directly to my_var?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are asking this because you simplified from a more general problem such as:

```
someprog args | read my_var
```

you should be using [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution):

```
my_var=$(someprog args)
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason read doesn't work in a pipe the way you have it is that it creates a subshell. Variables set in a subshell don't persist to their parents. See [BashFAQ/024](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Answer (score 2):

You can store the output of a command in a variable using either backticks or `$()` syntax:

```
my_var=`cat /some/file.txt`
```

Now the content of `/some/file.txt` is stored in $my_var.  Same thing, with different syntax:

```
my_var=$(cat /some/file.txt)
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work at the prompt.  My guess is you already have my_var set in your CLI, and are just retrieving that at the prompt.

Try this:

$ my_var="nothing"; echo "red sox" | read my_var; echo $my_var

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `my_var` variable to have a constant value, as in your question, why not just do:

```
my_var="red sox"
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? Please explain what you wan't to do first.

If you're trying to set a variable this is what you need:

```
my_var="red sox"
echo $my_var
```

If you need it globally you should set it in env:

```
export my_var
```